# Program crash at runtime

Tags: c++

What's the problem with this code, my program stops suddenly, without indicating the cause of the crash, what I'm trying to do is use the class members in the derived class (through the inheritance) and vice versa:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    void attribBase();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void attribDerived();
};

void Base::attribBase()
}
    Derived d;
    d.attribDerived();
}

void Derived::attribDerived()
{
    Base b;
    b.attribBase();
}

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Derived d;

    b.attribBase();
    d.attribDerived();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have infinite recursion. `attribDerived()` calls `attribBase()`, which calls `attribDerived()`.

Comment: `b.attribBase();` creates a Derived object that call `d.attribDerived();` that creates a Base object that calls `b.attribBase();` that creates .... Infinite recursion

Comment: You really should indent your code.  It is hard to see where one class or function begins and ends when you write everything flushed against the left margin of the edit window.

Comment: You're not doing anything through inheritance. When Derived calls attrbiBase, it's doing it in an entirely separate object.

Comment: It's a simple [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898401/program-crash-at-runtime) -- `attribDerived` calls `attribBase` and `attribBase` calls `attribDerived`.

Comment: Some people think that all questions are futile, just because they have the answer, thanks to those who answered with politeness.

Answer (score 0):

Your Program has a infinite recursion.
Because of that Stack overflow happened.
And the process get terminated.

break the infinite function calls.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is infinite loop. The attribDerived() function calls the attribBase() function then attribBase() calls attribDerived() then attribDerived() calls attribBase()....The functions are calling each other with no conditions to stop the loop.

Depending on your compiler, you are not getting an error because there are no syntax and logic error. The loops works but we know it doesn't do anything useful.

I'm also getting an impression, from what you wrote "vice-versa", that you are thinking the attribDervied() function is calling through the Base class to its attribBase() function. However, remember that inheriting means the Derived class gets a copy of everything the Base class has. attribDerived() is not searching for a function outside of its class for the attribBase(). Thus, the attribDerived() is just calling its sibling function(attribBase() in the Derived class).

Hope this clarifies your problem :)